# How to get id from li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to get the li id ​​from the following code?

I need it for my project, I already researched and tried but only appears "null"

```
window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
  var list = document.getElementById('dropBox').children;
  var result = "Names are: <br />";
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      result += document.getElementById(list[i]) + "<br />";
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: COMPLETE LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/urv7sby4/1/

Comment: Where's that "following code"? It does not contain any "li" but `list`?

Comment: what appears `null`? where are the `li` items you are talking about? What are the expected and the actual results of the code you provided? Please clarify your question and provide [mcve] in your post itself (if you show some code only in the fiddle, those bits should be only supplementary, with question remaining clear even if the link gets broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the id of an element, you can access the `id`-property of the object.

For your example it would be like this:

```
window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('dropBox').children;
    var result = "Names are: <br />";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        result += list[i].id + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
}
```

But since it seems that you want the Names and not the object-id, you have the option to get the text-content of the elements by accessing the `textContent`-property like this:

```
window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('dropBox').children;
    var result = "Names are: <br />";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        result += list[i].textContent + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also changed the location of br for a more legible code.

```js
window.dragStart = function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.getAttribute("id"));
}
window.dragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
window.drop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    //when i dropped an element and if i made mistake, by clicking on element i remove it from dropbox
    var txt1 = document.getElementById(data);
    txt1.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById(data).remove();
    this.remove();};        
}

window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('dropBox').children;
    var result = "Names are: <br></br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        result += list[i].textContent;
        result +=  "<br><br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```css
#dropBox {
     width: 150px;
     height: 200px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     background: lightyellow;
     text-align: left;
     margin: 20px 0;
     color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Drag & Drop Demo</h2>
<p>Drag and drop the image into the drop box:</p>
<div id="dropBox" ondragover="dragOver(event);" ondrop="drop(event);" >
</div>

<!--for some reason when i drop element in dropbox, it doesn't go in new line, so i wrote this <br>. If you have better solution, please tell me.-->
<ul>
<li id="dragA" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event);">Marko      
Maric</li>
</ul>


<input type='button' onclick='saveAndDisplay()' value='Submit'/> 

<!--by clicking on submit button, I want the names i picked to display in this paragraph-->

<p id="demo">Names are:</p>

</body>
</html>
```